Macro Hedging Bond Index Total Returns with IRS to get Excess Return over Swaps
I have the historical total return and duration index data for a bond index, and I want to get the excess returns, over swaps.
I have access to historical swap rates from bloomberg.
How can I calculate the swap-hedged returns for this index ?
